# scale by specific dimensions - illustrator transform effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, scale

Is there a way to use transform effect to scale to a specific measurement instead of percentage?

I have ran into this thread
but it talks about the "transform each" tool and not the transform effect

for example -

here is an example of a wanted result

[image]

you can see that the distance between the stars is fixed

here is an example of a the same thing using transform effect

[image]

you can see that the distance between the stars is getting shorter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a step blend instead.

1. Create a star with a stroke and no fill, then do *Object > Transform > Scale*. Make sure to uncheck "Scale Strokes and Effects", increase the scale as required, then hit *Copy* to create a larger star.

[image]

2. Select both stars, and do *Object > Blend > Make*
3. Do *Object > Blend > Blend Options*. Choose "Specified Steps". Apply the number of steps required.

Example

[image]